# How to sort a list of items by clicking on checkboxes using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following list of items and i use jquery to sort them by eg (Best Rating, Minimum Order etc.)

It works pretty fine when i sort the items by Rating as i get the best rated items at the top of the list. 
My problem is when i try to sort the items by minimum order amount. I want to get the lowest price at the top of the list.

Take a look at my code bellow:

```js
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

var sl = $('.storesList')
  
sl.children().reverse().each(function(i) {
  $(this).data({
    original: i + 1,
    rating: +$(".rating", this).text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ""),
     minimumorder: +$(".minorder", this).text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ""),
    open: $(".open-or-close-tag", this).text() === "CLOSE" ? 0 : 1
  })

})


$('#count').text($('.storesList  .store-block:visible').length);
$(".checkboxes-area").change(function() {
  var byRate = $("#by-rate").prop("checked")
  var isOpen = $("#stores-open-now").prop("checked")
  var byminOrder = $("#by-minimum-order").prop("checked")
  var s = sl.children().get().sort(function(a, b) {
    var aSort = key(a),
        bSort = key(b)
    return aSort < bSort ? 1 : aSort === bSort ? 0 : -1
  })
  $(sl).append(s)


  function key(el) {
    var res = $(el).data("original") * 0.00001
    if (byRate) res = $(el).data("rating")
    if (byminOrder) res = $(el).data("minimumorder")
    if (isOpen) res *= $(el).data("open")
    return res
  }
})
```

```css
.storesList {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#count {
  display: inline-block;
}

.store-block {
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating {
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: 3px;
}

.minorder {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
  top: 3px;  
}

.open-or-close-tag {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.hide-me {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-lab {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes-area">
  <label class="checkbox-lab"><span>OPEN FIRST</span>
 <input type="checkbox" id="stores-open-now">
</label>


<label class="checkbox-lab"><span>BEST RATED</span>
<input type="checkbox" id="by-rate">
</label>

<label class="checkbox-lab"><span>BY MINIMUM ORDER</span>
<input type="checkbox" id="by-minimum-order">
</label>



</div>


<div class="storesList">

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Apple Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.5</div>
    <div class="minorder">100 €</div>
    <div class="open-or-close-tag">CLOSE</div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Nokia Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 3.8</div>
    <div class="minorder">250 €</div>
    <div class="open-or-close-tag">OPEN</div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Samsung Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.0</div>
    <div class="minorder">25 €</div>
    <div class="open-or-close-tag">CLOSE</div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Linux</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.9</div>
    <div class="minorder">50 €</div>
    <div class="open-or-close-tag">OPEN</div>
  </div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's sorting in descending is that the compare function in the sort call is returning positive (+1) for `aSort < bSort`, which is fine for both "Open first" and "Best rated" but not for "By minimum order". All that needs to change is that you need to return negative amount for minimumorder as in the modified version of your code here (key method has been modified to return negative amount). You will need to fix the combination scenario by changing some conditions, like if you want both Open first and minimum order, that will not work together right now. Let me know if you need more help with this.

```js
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

var sl = $('.storesList')

sl.children().reverse().each(function(i) {
  $(this).data({
    original: i + 1,
    rating: +$(".rating", this).text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ""),
     minimumorder: +$(".minorder", this).text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ""),
    open: $(".open-or-close-tag", this).text() === "CLOSE" ? -1 : 1
  })
})

var slByOrderAmount = $.makeArray(sl.children().map(function(index, el){
  return $(el).data("minimumorder");
})).sort(function(a, b){return a - b}).reverse();

//console.log(slByOrderAmount);

$('#count').text($('.storesList  .store-block:visible').length);
$(".checkboxes-area").change(function() {
  var byRate = $("#by-rate").prop("checked");
  var isOpen = $("#stores-open-now").prop("checked");
  var byminOrder = $("#by-minimum-order").prop("checked");
  //console.log("ByRate = " + byRate + ", ByMinOrder = " + byminOrder + ", IsOpen = " + isOpen);
  sl.children().each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    //console.log("Name: " + $this.find(".store-name").html() + ", Original: " + $this.data("original") + ", Rating: " + $this.data("rating") + ", MinOrder: " + $this.data("minimumorder") + ", Open: " + $this.data("open") + ", Result: " + key(this));
  });
  var s = sl.children().get().sort(function(a, b) {
    var aSort = key(a),
        bSort = key(b)
    return aSort < bSort ? 1 : aSort === bSort ? 0 : -1
  });
  $(sl).append(s);


  function key(el) {
   var $el = $(el);
    var res = 1;
    if (byRate == true) res = $el.data("rating");
    if (byminOrder == true) res = slByOrderAmount.indexOf($el.data("minimumorder"));
    if (isOpen == true) res *= $el.data("open");
    res += $el.data("original") * 0.00001;
    return res;
  }
})
```

```css
.storesList {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#count {
  display: inline-block;
}

.store-block {
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating {
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: 3px;
}

.minorder {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
  top: 3px;  
}

.open-or-close-tag {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.hide-me {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-lab {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes-area">
  <label class="checkbox-lab"><span>OPEN FIRST</span>
 <input type="checkbox" id="stores-open-now">
</label>


<label class="checkbox-lab"><span>BEST RATED</span>
<input type="checkbox" id="by-rate">
</label>

<label class="checkbox-lab"><span>BY MINIMUM ORDER</span>
<input type="checkbox" id="by-minimum-order">
</label>



</div>


<div class="storesList">

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Apple Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.5</div>
    <div class="minorder">100 €</div>
    <div class="open-or-close-tag">CLOSE</div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Nokia Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 3.8</div>
    <div class="minorder">250 €</div>
    <div class="open-or-close-tag">OPEN</div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Samsung Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.0</div>
    <div class="minorder">25 €</div>
    <div class="open-or-close-tag">CLOSE</div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Linux</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.9</div>
    <div class="minorder">50 €</div>
    <div class="open-or-close-tag">OPEN</div>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yatin for your help. I guess, i will need both Open first and minimum order at the same time but first i will try to figure it out by myself. This is my way to learn coding :)

Comment: That's the best way in my opinion. Good luck with it mate.

Comment: Finally I really need your help. After many fails i cant get "Open First" and "Minimum Order" checked at the same time. Could you please give me an example how to make this work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, let me spend some time on it this morning. I'm sorry, I just looked at your comment now.

Comment: I've updated the post to allow doing both together. I didn't find it reliable to find mathematical values to change, it could be done with changing values but the min order amounts can vary a huge range so I decided to use a sorted array and used its index to get the new key for min order instead of the actual minorder value. That will work now. Have a look, hope it helps.